# How To Change date automatically as per time AM/PM

Tags: android

Hello I have to set date as per user selected time AM/PM

**My Code for time**

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener1 = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


            hours1=hourOfDay;
            min1=minute;
            SimpleDateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String newTime = formate.format(System.currentTimeMillis());


            updateTime1();


             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int years = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int months = 1 + c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int AM_orPM = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

                try{
                    if ((c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1) )
                    {
                        String PM = "";
                        if (AM_orPM == 1)
                        {
                            PM = "PM";
                        }
                        populateSetDate2(days, months, years);
                        Cabdate.setText("Refreshed on " + days + "-"
                        + months + "-" + years  + PM);

                    }
                    else if ((c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) )
                    {
                        String AM = "";
                        if (AM_orPM == 0)
                        {
                            AM = "AM";
                        }
                        populateSetDate2(ddd1, mmm1, ddd1);

                        Cabdate.setText("Refreshed on " + ddd1 + "-"
                        + mmm1 + "-" + yyy1 + AM);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){} 
           /* if(hours1>=hours)
            { 
                hours=hours1+5;

                Toast.makeText(AirlinecabBooking.this, "invalid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/



        }

    };
```

**For Date:**

```
@SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "NewApi" })
public class SelectDateFragment2 extends DialogFragment implements
OnDateSetListener {


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        yyy1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmm1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         ddd1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mmm1= mmm1 + 1;


        Calendar plus10days = Calendar.getInstance();
        plus10days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 31);
         d = plus10days.get(calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
            calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);



        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            populateSetDate2(yy, mm + 1, dd);



    }
}

public void populateSetDate2(int year, int month, int day) {






    if (year == yyy1) {

        if ((month >= mmm1) && (year == yyy1)) {


            if( day > ddd1 && day < d )
            {

                Cabdate.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                final_date=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
                System.out.println(final_date);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry Problem with date. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }

        else if (month >= mmm1 && year == yyy1) 
        {
            Cabdate.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            final_date=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
            System.out.println(final_date);
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry Problem with month. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry Problem with year. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Problem is when I select any time format am/pm it sets date as a current date even if I choose future date..

Here `Cabdate` is my date `textview`

Please help me
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getInstance();`   returns a `Calendar` instance initilalized with the current time in the default time zone. You should use `setTimeInMillis(long millis)` or `setTime(Date date)` to change the time in your `Calendar` instance.

When you dismiss your DatePiker

```
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePicker.getMonth();
int year =  datePicker.getYear();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);
```

Comment: plzzz explain me where do i initilalize setTimeInMillis(long millis) m confuse plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TimerTask scanTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();
scanTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                Date mydate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                String time = formatter.format(mydate);
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, time,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // textExpiry.setText(formatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                mTextTime.setText(time);

            }
        });
    }
};

t.schedule(scanTask, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: my date dose not change as per AM/PM PLZZZZZ help me

Comment: answer updated in dateFormat. This will give you time in AM PM format.

Comment: yeah it gives me in the formate of AM/PM but date dosent change for example if i choose 25th april date and set time....the date is automatcally set as a current date 22 april...:(